# Auto Replace URL with Mirror URL

Tags: bash, ubuntu, github, proxy, vpn

Due to company policy we cannot access GitHub directly from company network, it has to be done via a company mirror. This is very painful when we need to run codes that needs to download dependencies from GitHub.

Right now I have to go into the code files and replace line by line for every URL from "github.com/username/repo_name" to "company_mirror.com/username/repo_name" where company_mirror.com is our company mirror.

Just wondering is there a way I can change the setting somewhere so that whenever something tries to access github.com it will access company_mirror.com instead? Could this be achieved by adding a few lines in bashrc?

System: Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add one or more [`insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) rules to your configuration:

> `url.<base>.insteadOf`
>
> Any URL that starts with this value will be rewritten to start, instead, with <base>. In cases where some site serves a large number of repositories, and serves them with multiple access methods, and some users need to use different access methods, this feature allows people to specify any of the equivalent URLs and have Git automatically rewrite the URL to the best alternative for the particular user, even for a never-before-seen repository on the site. When more than one insteadOf strings match a given URL, the longest match is used.

In this example, something like this should work:

```
# Rewrite HTTPS requests to GitHub.com
git config --global url."https://company_mirror.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"

# Rewrite SSH requests to GitHub.com
git config --global url."git@company_mirror.com:".insteadOf "git@github.com:"
```

And the end result will be something like this in your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[url "https://company_mirror.com/"]
        insteadOf = "https://github.com/"

[url "git@company_mirror.com:"]
        insteadOf = "git@github.com:"
```

Comment: Thank yo so much, this has worked for most of the repos. However it did not work in the situation when the url is of the format https://<ACCESS_TOKEN>@github.com/<USERNAME>/<REPOSITORYNAME>.git since GitHub no longer supports password authentication and requires an access token now.

Comment: @赵舒宁Shuning, this strategy only works when matching leading characters. There's no way to match `https://...github.com/` unless the `...` part is fully specified. If you change those URLs from HTTPS to SSH it should work since authentication for SSH connections will be based on an SSH key instead of a token. I'm not aware of any strategy for doing this when HTTPS passwords (which is what the token is) are used in the URL.